# Why does NSView.scrollRectToVisible(rect) return false when moving up or left?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, appkit, nsscrollview

I am calling `scrollRectToVisible` in a subView of the `documentView` (within `NSScrollView`).

When I call it to programmatically scroll the view down or right, the results are as expected: (1) the function returns true and (2) the full rect passed to the function is made visible within the scrollView.

When I perform the exact same steps but for scrolling the view up or left (effectively towards the origin because my custom `NSView` is flipped) then nothing happens: (1) function returns false (indicating it won't be doing anything) and (2) the rect requested to be made visible in the scrollView is NOT made visible.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your clipview is flipped?

Comment: Yes clipView is flipped.

Comment: I am beginning to think it has something to do with the visibleRect of the underlying view.

Comment: so your documentView, clipView and scrollView are flipped? _I_ would then try to reproduce this in a small sample app

Answer (score 0):

The reason turned out to be that a part of my documentView was obstructed by headers on the top and left (`floatingSubviews`). This was causing what I was moving to go underneath the obstruction without needing to perform a scroll; whereas I was expecting it to scroll.